# how to define multidimentional array globally in laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to define multidimentional array in laravel controller globally.
I am defining it like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Communication_link;
use App\Contact;
use DateTime;
use App\Resource_status;
use App\Inquiry;
use App\Contact_communication;
use App\Pincode;
use App\City;
use App\User;

class createInquiryController extends Controller
{
    public $response;
    $map = array(
                  array("contact","id"),
                  array("communication_link", "id"),
                  array("contact_communication","id")
    );



    public function contact_select(Request $request){
            return $map;
    }
}
```

but this is throwing a error "undefined map".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define it and assign data in constructor:

```
protected $map;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->map = array(
        array("contact","id"),
        array("communication_link", "id"),
        array("contact_communication","id")
    );
}
```

Then you'll have access to this variable from any method in this controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = $this->map;
}
```